Yarn Install Request failed "304 Not Modified"
For a CapTP with native promises, see @endo/eventual-send and @endo/captp)
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/emojis-list/-/emojis-list-3.0.0.tgz: Request failed "304 Not Modified"
at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:696:66)
at new ResponseError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:802:124)
at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:66750:16)
at Request.emit (node:events:517:28)
at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:142287:10)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:700:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:541:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[Container] 2024/12/17 13:59:15.199693 Command did not exit successfully yarn exit status 1
[Container] 2024/12/17 13:59:15.208911 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/12/17 13:59:15.208929 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: yarn. Reason: exit status 1

https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/bxvmmvlqzfds

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
